# RangeError when trying to get flutter ExpansionPanel to expand

Tags: flutter

I saw the Widget of the Week at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aJZzRMziJc and copied the code to a State class that I cannot get to work.

```
class SearchResultsPageState extends State<SearchResultsPage> {
  final List<bool> _isOpen = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("test"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ExpansionPanelList(
          children: [
            ExpansionPanel(
              headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) => const Text('one'),
              body: const Text('one one\none'),
              isExpanded: _isOpen.isNotEmpty ? _isOpen[0] : false,
            ),
            ExpansionPanel(
              headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) => const Text('two'),
              body: const Text('two two\ntwo'),
              isExpanded: _isOpen.isNotEmpty ? _isOpen[1] : false,
            ),
          ],
          expansionCallback: (i, isOpen) => setState(() {
            _isOpen[i] = !isOpen;
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have breakpoints at:

```
isExpanded: _isOpen.isNotEmpty ? _isOpen[0] : false,

isExpanded: _isOpen.isNotEmpty ? _isOpen[1] : false,

expansionCallback: (i, isOpen) => setState(() {
  _isOpen[i] = !isOpen;
}),
```

The `expansionCallback` gets called on every click of the button but an `Error` is thrown  and the the `isExpanded` property is not re-evaluated. The console shows:

```
The following RangeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

And it points to:

```
_isOpen[i] = !isOpen;
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your _isOpen list is empty. Initialise list with default values and it will work for you

```
 final List<bool> _isOpen = [false, false];
```

For multiple data you can declare it like:

```
List<bool> _isOpen = List<bool>.filled(10, false);
```

Comment: I want to eventually have an infinitely scrollable list of panels so dynamically created. How can I initialize or maintain the bool list in this scenario?

Comment: At least you have to declare length of array and then assign false value to all. I have update my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a Widget that highly depends on boundaries like ListView, ExpansionPanel etc. You should be more careful with null/empty values for the boundaries to avoid errors like **"RangeError"**.

**REASON FOR ERROR**

In this case, your _isOpen is an empty bool list (`final List<bool> _isOpen = [];`). And you are trying to get `_isOpen[0]` or `_isOpen[1]` if 'isNotEmpty'.

You might be thinking all looks good right? Well NO!!

Dart handles `List[index]` with valid length. While You are trying to get an `index` that didn't yet exist after you think you already checked for not being empty.

**SOLUTION**

Use

```dart
final List<bool> _isOpen = [false, false];
```

Same reason we use

```dart
final bool _isLoading = false;
```

And not longer

```dart
final bool _isLoading;
```

Another way is to use `late` and initialize the `_isOpen` later before using it with the `ExpansionPanel`

```dart
late final List<bool> isOpen;
  
isOpen = [false, false];
```